# How to overlap and merge multiple audio files using ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, cross-fade

I am trying to merge multiple audio files into a single file but instead of concatenating which I can do using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -v debug -i file1.wav -i file2.wav -i file3.wav -filter_complex [0:0]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[out] -map [out] output.wav
```

Though this command works fine for concatenating, I want to overlap let's say the last 100ms of the end of the first file and 100ms of the start of the next file.

I am now trying to use 'acrossfade' filter that ffmpeg provides but I am not having any success with it.

```
ffmpeg -v debug -i file1.wav -i file2.wav -i file3.wav -filter_complex [0:a]acrossfade=d=0.100:c1=exp:c2=exp,[1:a]acrossfade=d=0.100:c1=exp:c2=exp,[2:a]acrossfade=d=0.100:c1=exp:c2=exp
```

This is what I have come up till now, but does not work as it throws '**Buffer is too short (n=0) for frame_length=1**' error.

The documentation is not very helpful, does anyone have any idea what can be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acrossfade is meant to create a transition between *two* inputs. So, each pair of inputs has to have acrossfade applied with the result being used as an input for the next acrossfade.

`ffmpeg -v debug -i file1.wav -i file2.wav -i file3.wav -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.100:c1=exp:c2=exp[a01];[a01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.100:c1=exp:c2=exp" out.wav`

**Edit**: your inputs are 16000 Hz, and your crossfade duration is 0.1s (!), which is less than 2 audio frames at the input sampling rate. Default frame size is 1024 samples. So, frame size needs to be lowered.

`ffmpeg -v debug -i file1.wav -i file2.wav -i file3.wav -filter_complex "[0:a]asetnsamples=256[0a];[1:a]asetnsamples=256[1a];[2:a]asetnsamples=256[2a];[0a][1a]acrossfade=d=0.100:c1=exp:c2=exp[a01];[a01][2a]acrossfade=d=0.100:c1=exp:c2=exp" out.wav`

Comment: Hey, I tried your command but it is throwing the following error:
`sh: 1: [a01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.100:c1=exp:c2=exp[2]: not found`

Also, can you explain what does [a01] and [2:a], I am still not very clear of the stream selection syntax and logic.

Comment: See edited command. `[a01]` is the label given to the output of the first acrossfade, which is then used as input for the next one.  `2:a` select audio from the third `-i` input.

Comment: Hey, I tried the edited command, it does not throw the previous but it is failing silently and outputting empty file. In the debug logs, I see the following things:
`cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 2 times
detected 4 logical cores
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x561b4d669bc0] query_formats: 7 queried, 18 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
Thanks for the explanation, so considering there be 4 files, the output of the first 2 merges will be labeled [a02], is that right?

Comment: this is the exact command I am running on version 4.0.2-2, let me know if version could be an issue.   
`ffmpeg -v debug -i file0.wav -i file1.wav -i file2.wav -filter_complex "[0][1]acrossfade=d=0.100:c1=exp:c2=exp[a01];[a01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.100:c1=exp:c2=exp" out.wav`

Comment: The label is arbitrary. It just allows the user to refer to the result (once) later.  Segfault indicates either a bug, or more likely, incompatible build for your machine. Upgrade and check.

Comment: I just upgraded to v4.1.1 and I am running it on Ubuntu 18.10 x86. But still, segfault is occurring. Is it possible the release does not work with Cosmic Cuttlefish?

Comment: Instead of doing for 3 files when I tried to do it for 2 files, following is the message I receive:
`Filter acrossfade has an unconnected output   
[AVIOContext @ 0xd3c9a00] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts   
[AVIOContext @ 0xd3963c0] Statistics: 160142 bytes read, 1 seeks   
[AVIOContext @ 0xd3a1b40] Statistics: 96846 bytes read, 1 seeks   `

It says filter acrossfade has an unconnected output file.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: I cannot share the entire log here because of character limitations, sharing the link where you can view the entire log.  

https://codeshare.io/anOEdn

Comment: Check the same link, I have updated it with the Segfault log.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, sorry I am not yet that familiar with frame size and sampling rates.   
Also, yes 0.1s is clearly noticeable but what is happening now is, it is not throwing any errors but it is clipping off the mentioned duration instead of overlaying it on the previous files. What do you think could be the reason for that and I have copied the same exact command. **Edit:** File 1: 7s, File 2: 4s, File 3: 14s. It clips 0.1s from 2nd and 3rd files.

Comment: You're using exp curve. Try tri.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a ton! Lastly, can you tell me why did exp clipped while tri didn't?

Comment: exp means exponential so the first audio will drop out very quickly, and second audio will rise very quickly. Over a 0.1 s interval,the first will sound clipped.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your time!